# Selection problem of bucketlist in sortable package

Tags: r, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable

There are 3 districts which are A, B, and C in my data. I would like to establish a new district from the subdistricts of the current districts. For example, I select 2 of 3 districts via selectInput. And then, I would like to use bucket_list for selecting the subdistricts. The bucket list should show the subdistricts of selected districts. I do not want to see subdistricts of 3rd districts on a bucket list. I want to see only what I selected via selectInput. I could not manage this. After that, I want to create some tables using the DT package based on what I selected in the bucket list. My codes are below. I would be happy if you could help.

Here’s code:

```
library(shiny)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(sortable)
library(gsheet)

data <- gsheet2tbl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TqFoIQzTYyWKP8N43jcAxAV71TTA7ldfeRcGtpqfarM/edit#gid=201611728')



ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(color = "green",title = "NEW DISTRICT", inverted = TRUE, size = "very wide"),
   dashboardSidebar(
       size = "thin", color = "teal",
       sidebarMenu(
           menuItem(tabName = "dist", "NEW DISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT", icon = icon("tree")),
           menuItem(tabName = "subdist", "NEW SUBDISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT", icon = icon("tree"))
           
       )
   ),
   dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
           selected = 1,
           tabItem(
               tabName = "dist",
               fluidRow(
                   fluidPage( textInput("caption", "ENTER THE NAME OF THE NEW DISTRICT", "", width = 500, placeholder = "PLEASE ENTER NEW NAME HERE!"),
                              
                              
                              fluidRow(column(5, verbatimTextOutput("value1"))),
                              hr(),
                              
                              
                              fluidPage(
                                  
                                  
                                  selectInput("select", label = h3("PLEASE SELECT THE DISTRICTS!"), 
                                              choices = (data$DISTRICT),
                                              selected = 0,
                                              multiple= TRUE),
                                  
                                  hr(),
                                  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
                                  
                              ),
                              
                              
                              
                   ),
                   if(interactive()) {
                       bucket_list(
                           header = c("NEW DISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT"),
                           add_rank_list(
                               text = "PLEASE SELECT SUBDISTRICT HERE!",
                               labels = "x",
                               options = sortable_options(
                                   multiDrag = TRUE),
                           ),
                           add_rank_list(
                               text = "select the subdistricts of the new district"
                           ),
                           add_rank_list(
                               text = "select the subdistrict of the current district"
                           ),
                           add_rank_list(
                               text = "select the subdistrict of the current district 2"
                           )    
                       )
                   }
                   
               ),
               
               )
           )
       ), 
       theme = "cerulean"
   )


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   
   observe({ print(input$select) 
       #output$x <- data$SUBDISTRICT[data$DISTRICT == input$select]  
       #output$x <- data %>% filter(DISTRICT == input$select) %>% select(SUBDISTRICT) 
       #updateSelectInput(session,"SUBDISTRICT","Select a SUBDISTRICT Category",choices = unique(x))
   })
   
   output$value <- renderText({paste(input$select)
       
       
       
   })
   
   output$value1 <- renderText({ input$caption })
   
   

   })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also, when I remove # on these codes:

```
observe({ print(input$select) 
       #output$x <- data$SUBDISTRICT[data$DISTRICT == input$select]  
       #output$x <- data %>% filter(DISTRICT == input$select) %>% select(SUBDISTRICT) 
       #updateSelectInput(session,"SUBDISTRICT","Select a SUBDISTRICT Category",choices = unique(x))
```

The shiny close itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will meet your needs

```
library(shiny)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(sortable)
library(gsheet)

data <- gsheet2tbl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TqFoIQzTYyWKP8N43jcAxAV71TTA7ldfeRcGtpqfarM/edit#gid=201611728')

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(color = "green",title = "NEW DISTRICT", inverted = TRUE, size = "very wide"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    size = "thin", color = "teal",
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(tabName = "dist", "NEW DISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT", icon = icon("tree")),
      menuItem(tabName = "subdist", "NEW SUBDISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT", icon = icon("tree"))
      
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      selected = 1,
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dist",
        fluidRow(
          fluidPage( textInput("caption", "ENTER THE NAME OF THE NEW DISTRICT", "", width = 500, placeholder = "PLEASE ENTER NEW NAME HERE!"),
                     
                     
                     fluidRow(column(5, verbatimTextOutput("value1"))),
                     hr(),
                     
                     fluidPage(
                       
                       selectInput("select", label = h3("PLEASE SELECT THE DISTRICTS!"), 
                                   choices = unique(data$DISTRICT),
                                   selected = 0,
                                   multiple= TRUE),
                       
                       hr(),
                       fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
                       DTOutput("t1"),
                       selectInput("subdistrict", label = h3("PLEASE SELECT THE SUBDISTRICTS!"), 
                                   choices = unique(data$SUBDISTRICT),
                                   selected = 0,
                                   multiple= TRUE)
                       
                     )
          ),
          uiOutput("mybucket")
        ),
        
      )
    )
  ), 
  theme = "cerulean"
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- reactive({
    data[data$DISTRICT %in% req(input$select),]
  })
  
  output$mybucket <- renderUI({
    req(dat())
    bucket_list(
      header = c("NEW DISTRICT ESTABLISHMENT"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "PLEASE SELECT SUBDISTRICT HERE!",
        labels = unique(dat()$SUBDISTRICT),
        options = sortable_options(
          multiDrag = TRUE),
      ),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "select the subdistricts of the new district"
      ),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "select the subdistrict of the current district"
      ),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "select the subdistrict of the current district 2"
      )    
    )
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT(dat())
  
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    updateSelectInput(session,"subdistrict","Select a SUBDISTRICT Category",choices = unique(dat()$SUBDISTRICT))
    
  })
  
  output$value <- renderText({paste(input$select)})
  
  output$value1 <- renderText({ input$caption })
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. I would like to have the tables based on the selection of the bucket lists. For example, I have three bucket lists in my case. So, I need to have three different tables. Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

Comment: @mko, I thought this question was about selection problem as noted in the title. The proper etiquette is then to accept the answer, if it answered your original post, and then ask new question as a separate question (on SO) on tables or other issues, if you are not able to solve.